# How to zoom on UIView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

In my iOS app I want my users to be able to zoom in on the screen.  My main uiview contains several subviews which contain images.  I want my uipinchgesturerecognizer to either change the scale, or ideally use some "zoom" rather than scaling each subview.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use an UIScrollView with zoom enabled? Put your UIView in a UIScrollView with zoom enabled and check the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `UIScrollView`. First create a scroll view as the base of your view hierarchy, putting your previous container view as a subview of the scroll view. Set the `delegate` of the scroll view to self and implement the delegate method `viewForZoomingInScrollView`, in which you should return the view that will be zoomed in (your original container view). This will allow the user to pinch and zoom your original UIView.

Comment: Thank you so much.  From your comment I searched and found another resource which helped me get the desired result.  This is exactly what I needed.  I added a scrollview to my view controller on my storyboard, and used the zoomForZoomingInScrollView method as suggested.  This method worked great because I don't have to scale my images, just zoom my view.  Thanks so much guys:   http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide advice on this without having a clearer view of what exactly you want to achieve.

Can you include a link to a sketch? For example, do you want the individual subviews to remain the same size but the layout to change ? Do you want the individual subviews to resize but their contents to be upscaled?

If you simple want to treat the subview as (basically) a single image which just happens to have other images in it, then maybe it would be better to render it as one and then scale that?